# When I use pygame.transform.rotate(), it moves my image so that, if used in succession, it will go off screen. Why?

Tags: python, pygame, transformation

So I loaded an image, then used rotate on it. However, when I ran the program, it just slid off screen. Why?

```
import pygame, sys




def rotate45(gameObject):
    newObject = pygame.transform.rotate(gameObject, 45)
    return newObject

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
    Tardis = pygame.image.load("Tardis.bmp")
    Tardis.set_colorkey((255, 0, 0))









    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill( (0,0,0) )

        Tardis = rotate45(Tardis)

        screen.blit(Tardis, (400,300))

        pygame.display.update()
```

Can somebody help? My image is 75 x 134 if you need to know.

I am new to programming, but I have no clue why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @cmd says, the `rotate` transformation alters the dimensions of the object. Save the original object and continue to apply the altered transformation to the original object. Below is an example:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time

def rotate45(gameObject, rotations={}):
    r = rotations.get(gameObject,0) + 45
    rotations[gameObject] = r
    return pygame.transform.rotate(gameObject, r)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
    Tardis = pygame.image.load("Tardis.bmp")
    Tardis.set_colorkey((255, 0, 0))

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill( (0,0,0) )
        rotatedTardis = rotate45(Tardis)
        screen.blit(rotatedTardis, (400,300))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all images are rectangles.  If you start with an image that is 75x134 and rotate it 45 degrees, the new rectangle will be bigger(147x147) since the 45 degree image needs to fit within the new rectangle.  Then this new rectangle will be rotated again 45 degrees and will need (207x 207)... etc.  Eventually it will get so big the Tardis rectangle is mostly background and the original image is off the screen even if the top left is in the same spot.  What you should do is leave the original image alone and just increase the amount that you are rotating the image each time you need to draw it.

```
...
tardis_angle = 0
while True:
    # Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    # update game state
    tardis_angle = (tardis_angle + 45) % 360

    # draw
    screen.fill( (0,0,0) )
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.rotate(Tardis, tardis_angle), (400,300))
    pygame.display.update()
```